Azure API Management platform version stv1 to stv2
As you might know that Azure API Management platform version stv1 is being deprecated in August 2024.
And now we need to migrate it to the latest one and which is stv2.
I have Terraform code which provisions the API Mgt.
What I have done that I have deleted the old API mgt which was on platform version stv1 and then provision it again but it has still provisioned on the old platform stv1.
Do you happen to know how we can specify the platform_version in the terraform code?
And here is the official documentation page of terraform
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management
but I don't find any attribute regarding platform version.

Maybe best to search/ask directly on that project:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+azurerm_api_management

try upgrading the terraform provider version >3.47.0 the newly api platform version will get migrated to stv2.
